# PySpark: Calculate grouped-by AUC

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

- Spark version: 1.6.0

I tried computing AUC (area under ROC) grouped by the field `id`. Given the following data:

```
# Within each key-value pair
# key is "id"
# value is a list of (score, label)
data = sc.parallelize(
         [('id1', [(0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.0)),
          ('id2', [(0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.0))
         ]
```

The [BinaryClassificationMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics) class can calculate the AUC given a list of `(score, label)`.

I want to compute AUC by key (i.e. `id1, id2`). But how to "map" a `class` to an RDD by key?

#### Update

I tried to wrap the `BinaryClassificationMetrics` in a function:

```
def auc(scoreAndLabels):
    return BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels).areaUnderROC
```

And then map the wrapper function to each values:

```
data.groupByKey()\
    .mapValues(auc)
```

But the list of `(score, label)` is in fact of type `ResultIterable` in `mapValues()` while the `BinaryClassificationMetrics` expects `RDD`.

Is there any approach of converting the `ResultIterable` to `RDD` so the the `auc` function can be applied? Or any other workaround for computing group-by AUC (without importing third-party modules like scikit-learn)?

Comment: Using third party code is actually a pretty good choice. While getting AUC by hand is not that hard it is rather tedious by hand. Using `BinaryClassificationMetrics` from the other hand doesn't make much sense if individual classes are small enough to be handled with local data structures.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `BinaryClassificationMetrics` you can use [sklearn.metrics.auc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) and map each RDD element value and you'll get your AUC value per key:

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc

data = sc.parallelize([
         ('id1', [(0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.0)]),
         ('id2', [(0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.0)])])

result_aucs = data.map(lambda x: (x[0] + '_auc', auc(*zip(*x[1]))))
result_aucs.collect()


Out [1]: [('id1_auc', 0.15000000000000002), ('id2_auc', 0.15000000000000002)]
```

Comment: There is a minor typo in your last line of code, should be result

Comment: Do I have to install sklearn on each node of the Spark cluster in such case?

Comment: yes, you do. I usually `pip install` everything I need across all machines using `parallel-ssh` or `dsh` after I bring up a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get `auc` without using `sklearn`:

```
keys = data.map(lambda x: x[0]).distinct().collect()
rslt = {}
for k in keys:
    scoreAndLabels = data.filter(lambda x: x[0]==k).flatMap(lambda x: x[1])
    rslt[k] = BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels).areaUnderROC

print(rslt)
```

**Note:** this solution requires that the number of `key` is small enough to fit in the memory.

If you have so many keys that you can't `collect()` them into memory, don't use this