# Scala Spark : Calculate grouped-by AUC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to computing the AUC (area under ROC) grouped by a key field using the scala API, similarly to the following question : [PySpark: Calculate grouped-by AUC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582385/pyspark-calculate-grouped-by-auc).

Unfortunately, I can't use `sklearn`. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will be using the same method used in sklearn/mllib which is the [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). It's a technique used for **approximating** the definite integral.

It's quite straight-forward, you can find the same code in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/AreaUnderCurve.scala#L26).

```scala
def trapezoid(points: Seq[(Double, Double)]): Double = {
    require(points.length == 2)
    val x = points.head
    val y = points.last
    (y._1 - x._1) * (y._2 + x._2) / 2.0
}

def areaUnderCurve(curve: Iterable[(Double, Double)]): Double = {
    curve.toIterator.sliding(2).withPartial(false).aggregate(0.0)(
      seqop = (auc: Double, points: Seq[(Double, Double)]) => auc + trapezoid(points),
      combop = _ + _
    )
}

val seq = Seq((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 0.0))
areaUnderCurve(seq)
// res77: Double = 4.0
```

The result is **4.0** as expected.

Now let's apply that on a dataset. Data is already grouped by a key here :

```scala
val data = Seq(("id1", Array((0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.0))), ("id2", Array((0.5, 1.0), (0.6, 0.0), (0.7, 1.0), (0.8, 0.3)))).toDF("key","values")

case class Record(key : String, values : Seq[(Double,Double)])

data.as[Record].map(r => (r.key, r.values, areaUnderCurve(r.values))).show
// +---+--------------------+-------------------+
// | _1|                  _2|                 _3|
// +---+--------------------+-------------------+
// |id1|[[0.5, 1.0], [0.6...|0.15000000000000002|
// |id2|[[0.5, 1.0], [0.6...|0.16500000000000004|
// +---+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. What's more, I understand the importance to read source code

Comment: @nick_liu the best way to learn a framework is to read it's source code.