# Use a custom metric function in PySpark Datafame

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, scikit-learn

I have defined a custom function in python to calculate class-wise auc scores in a one-vs-rest fashion. It takes true classes and the probabilities for different classes as input and returns class-wise auc scores.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import pandas as pd

def mclass_auc(y_true, y_pred, n_class):
    tp = {}
    fp = {}
    aucs = {}
    for i in range(n_class):
    classes = [0]*n_class
    classes[i] = 1
    fp[i] tp[i], th = roc_curve(y_true.replace(list(range(n_class)), classes), y_pred[:, i])
    aucs[i] = auc(fp[i], tp[i])
    return aucs
```

For the sake of simplicity, I am generating some probability values which don't sum up to one.

```
cola = [np.random.randint(40, 81)/100 for i in range(10000)]
colb = [np.random.randint(30, 801)/1000 for i in range(10000)]
colc = [np.random.randint(40, 81)/200 for i in range(10000)]

coly = [np.random.randint(0, 4) for i in range(10000)]

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'0':cola, '1':colb, '2':colc, 'y':coly})

y_true = sample_df['y']
y_pred = sample_df[['1','2','3']].values

auc_multiclass(y_true, y_pred, 3)
sql.createDataFrame(sample_df)
```

In python, I can use the above function. Can someone help me calculate this in PySpark data frame setting? Changing it to pandas data frame and calculating was failing in this case.

Comment: did you try udf? can you post what you tried?

Comment: the examples that were present online were based on `sc.parallelize()`. But in my case, it did not work.

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37587466/6597727

This is the example I was trying to replicate, but it was failing at `sc.parallelize(spark_df)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def mclass_auc_spark(y_true, y_pred, n_class):
    aucs = {}
    for i in range(n_class):
        pred = y_pred.select(str(i)).withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
        true = y_true.withColumn('y', F.when(F.col('y') == i, 1.0).otherwise(0.0)).withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
        pred_labels = pred.join(true,on='row_id')
        metric = BinaryClassificationMetrics(pred_labels.select('y',str(i)).rdd)
        aucs[i] = metric.areaUnderROC
    return aucs

spark_df = sql.createDataFrame(sample_df)

y_true = spark_df.select('y')
y_pred = spark_df.select('0','1','2')

auc_scores = mclass_auc(y_true, y_pred, 3)
```